# Which actors were originally considered for the role of Spock in the Star Trek series?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

Please include pilot *and* the original series, if that is pertinent.

Comment: BTW I ran across some tongue-in-cheek alternate names for Spock's character that were written in a memo to Gene Roddenberry during the show's creation. I think it was retold in the book "The Making of Star Trek" by Stephen Whitfield & Gene Roddenberry. There was a whole list of names, including Splik, Splunk, Spik, and Spunk.

Comment: Hard to imagine anything other than "Spock", right?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the Star Trek Interview Book, Allen Asherman says that Deforest Kelley claims that Gene Rodenberry offered him the role before production of The Cage began. Another source I've seen, however, says that when Rodenberry saw Nimoy's features, no other actors were ever considered over Nimoy. There was however, a backup plan if Nimoy turned the role down: Martin Landau*

*I believe the source for that was [Star Trek Creator](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0451454189), but I'm not entirely sure.

Answer (score 3):

@FinalDraft is right about Martin Landau. He (Martin Landau) is interviewed about this in the [PBS Pioneers of Television: Science Fiction](http://www.pbs.org/opb/pioneersoftelevision/pioneering-programs/science-fiction/) episode. Martin Landau doesn't sound like he would have enjoyed the part, had he even been offered it.